# Why char* and int* behaves differently

Tags: c++, pointers, char, int

There are some doubts related to given program below. Any discussion will be helpful to understand the internals.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    char* ptr = new char[11];
    ptr = "helloworld";
    cout << ptr;

    int* ptr1 = new int[2];
    //ptr1 = {12, 24};
    cout << ptr1;

    return 0;
}
```

1. cout << ptr; prints helloworld (prints value); cout << ptr1 prints address not value. Why??
2. Since cout << ptr; prints value, How to get address that new char[11] assigns to ptr.
3. If ptr = "helloworld"; is allowed. why  ptr1 = {12, 24};  is not allowed?

Comment: 1. Because `const char *` has a separate overload, since it usually represents strings. 2. Cast to `(void *)`. 3. Because the standard says so.

Comment: `ptr = "helloworld";` is not allowed either, because `ptr` is `char*`.

Comment: @Nawaz Why it is not allowed. ptr is char*, and "helloworld" is array of char, so what's the problem?? You can check here. http://ideone.com/QsqKrN Its allowed.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal String literals are arrays of `const char`.

Comment: @nawaz If i am not wrong char* ptr is treated as const char* ptr. If not then i will make char* ptr as const char* ptr. Then it will be allowed right?

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal "`char* ptr` is treated as `const char* ptr`" - ??? They are two different (and incompatible) types. The `ptr = "string literal";` assignment discards the `const` qualifier. It lets you to modify a string literal, which is illegal.

Comment: @H2CO3, so  your first answer "Because const char * has a separate overload", is not apply here. because in my question i am using char* not const char*.  OR char* also has a separate overload, so answer is still valid??

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal It is legal to convert a pointer-to-non-`const` to a pointer-to-`const`  (and it is indeed done implicitly here). Only the conversion in the opposite direction is prohibited (think about it, and you'll know why).

Comment: why do you set your char* first and then set it again to hello world?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The heart of your question is why does the << operator output a string in one case but an address in another.  This is from it's c language heritage where there wasn't a 'true' string type.  In  c/c++ char* and char[] are handled uniquely and generally assumed to be a 'string'.  Arrays of other types are assumed to be arrays of that type.  So when outputting a char* the << assumes you want a string output, while with int[], it outputs the address of the array rather than it's content.  Simply, char[] and char* are treated as special cases in a lot of output functions.

I can see that you also have some confusion regarding the way the compilers processes your source.  Consider:

```
char* ptr = new char[11];
ptr = "helloworld";
```

This code allocations 11 char's of memory and sets ptr to the address of that allocation.  The next line creates a constant "helloworld" which is allocated and initialized and sets ptr to the address of that memory.  You have two memory locations, one with 11 uninitialized chars and one initialized to "helloworld\0".

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a major problem with your code, and that is a memory leak. You allocate memory and assign it to `ptr`, but then you *reassign* it to make it point somewhere else. If you want the memory to contain a string you have to copy it into the allocated memory.

And "literal arrays" are not allowed by the language, except when initializing an array in a declaration.

Comment: While this is true (and important), it doesn't address any of the questions above.

Comment: @joachim

is that  reassign it to make it point somewhere else? Is ptr = "helloworld"; is not equivalent to

ptr[0] = 'h'
ptr[1] = 'e'
ptr[2] = 'l'
.
.
.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Why would it be equivalent? A pointer is not an array.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So it i want to avoid ptr[0] = 'h' ptr[1] = 'e' ptr[2] = 'l' . . .then is there any other way, so i can store "helloworld" in allocated memory in one go??

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal You want to use `std::copy()` then.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to understand the things.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Either copy using the generic [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), or using the old C-style [`std::strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).